# syntax error in my postgres statement for alter sequence

Tags: postgresql

UPDATE:

using postgres 14,

I just get error :Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ok"

---

This is my database:

```
-- Sequence and defined type
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS id_seq;

-- Table Definition
CREATE TABLE "public"."ok" (
    "id" int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('id_seq'::regclass),
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

And I want to modify the sequence:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE ok_id_seq RESTART;
```

I keep getting errors at ok_id_seq.

I tried id_seq only

Tried quotes everywhere.

Comment: 1) Postgres version? 2) What is the exact error message?  3) What happens if you do `select * from id_seq`? Add answers as update to question.

Comment: I did do "select * from id_seq" and I get results but I have other tables...So I tried ok.id_seq but I I get errors

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the **complete** and _exact_ error message you get.

Comment: Ok I posted my answer. But can only press accept in two days

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I now learnt that sequences are not table specific. I was trying to do alter table alter sequence.

I also used `SELECT * FROM information_schema.sequences;` to view all available sequences.

I don't know what happened so I recreated the table, checked for the sequence name.
Then was able to alter it with restart

Comment: So `ALTER SEQUENCE id_seq RESTART;` worked?

Comment: yes..................

Comment: If you want table specific then you need [Generate Always](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) *GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT } AS IDENTITY [ ( sequence_options ) ]*. This will create an `IDENTITY` column that you restart using `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ... RESTART` per [Alter Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html).